# Stop Mesh rendering if it intersect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I am generating a camera frustum mesh through code and it is working fine.

Now I am searching for a solution (shader based or else) to restrict
the camera frustum mesh if it intersects with any object. As you can see in the image, my frustum is passing through the plane which is not correct.

How can I control it? I searched and tried to apply different kinds of shaders but nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: The frustum is a mathematical entity, that uses FOV, near and far clip plane. I doubt you can change the corner positions.What is your purpose in this? Maybe there is something else.

Comment: The primary purpose is to show that how much area a camera is covering.   That are will be highlight through the mesh so that the main camera can view it.

Answer (score 2):

Get the frustum planes of the camera.

```
Plane[] frustumPlanes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(Camera.main); //Or whatever camera you are using
```

For each GameObject in the scene, get its `Renderer` component's `bounds` if any.

```
Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
if (renderer != null) 
{
  //get renderer.bounds
}
```

Test if the renderers bounds intersect with any of the frustum planes.

```
bool canSee = GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(frustumPlanes, renderer.bounds);

if (canSee) 
{
  //do something
}
```

This should be a pretty good approximation of whether your camera can "see" the mesh (i.e if the frustum intersects with any object)

Comment: actually i am not using this way to generating my mesh of frustum

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Irregardless of how you generate your frustum meshes, get your frustum planes (from your frustum mesh), and check for intersection with all the `GameObject`'s `Renderer`'s `bounds`.

Comment: This is so tricky so long and not efficient. further it can't help me to stop meshrendering at particular point.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Testing bounds interesection with planes is generally efficient. To stop meshrendering just disable the meshrenderer, `renderer.enabled = false;`